# Bootstrap Slider Border Radius

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Good night friends! Here I'm again, sorry.

At this blog I've done (http://bloganacastro.com/) the bootstrap slider is working properly. Only when we click at next slider the img lose the border-radius. I think it's because of some class "right" or "left" or "prev" or "next". Tried some things but didn't work.

If someone more expert could help that will be great.

Thanks until now!

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking, can you please clarify your question, perhaps with a JSFiddle

Comment: I can see Images with `border-radius`. can you put images showing your problem.?

Comment: I viewed via Chrome and FF.  In FF, it is fine.  In Chrome, it appears that the border radius is disappearing during the transition, but re-appears once the image is done loading.  Are you saying that is the issue?

Comment: Yes! Exactly! @cfnerd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok here's the html to look more closely at:

```html
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item">
            <img width="1053" height="416" src="http://bloganacastro.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/91.png" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="91">
```

The "carousel-inner" class is decorating the container for the slideshow and has the border-radius set. Just make sure this container is always on top so that the content slides and their prickly square corners don't show through - so just add for example "z-index: 99"

Hey Rodrigo, normally you say good night on parting ;-) Say rather at the start Good evening :-)

Comment: Thank you so much Kieran! And I'll follow your tip! Thanks!! :-)